# How to get the list of terms with its CPT?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I have a map in my website with dots that I localize the number of office per country on a map picture.

How it works is basically I have CPT as `office` and I create posts as city name like New York, London etc.

For example, if I have an office in New York, USA, I will create the post as New York and custom category will be country name as the USA. Also, in `office` CPT, I have custom fields for coordinating the dots on the map as Home_x and Home_Y.

So the outcome with the below code is like:

- USA/New York
- USA/Chicago
- United Kingdom/London
- United Kingdom/Bristol
- Spain/Barcelona
- Spain/Granada

My code for loop is;

```
    <div class="map-wrapper">
        <div class="map">

            <?php

            $terms = get_terms(array(
                'taxonomy' => 'office-country',
                'hide_empty' => false,
            ));
            ?>
            <?php foreach ($terms as $term) : ?>
                <?php
                $re = explode('-', $term->name);
                $args = array (
                    'post_type' => 'office', //
                    'posts_per_page' => -1,
                    'order' => 'ASC',
                    'tax_query'     => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy'  => 'office-country',
                            'field'     => 'id',
                            'terms'     => $term->term_id,
                        ),
                    ),
                );
                $query = new WP_Query( $args );
                if( $query->have_posts() ){
                    while( $query->have_posts() ){
                        $query->the_post();
                        $title =  get_the_title();
                        $info = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_post_info', true);
                        $link = get_term_meta($term->term_id, 'link', true);
                        ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $link ?>"
                           class="point <?php if ($term->slug === $_GET['country']) echo 'active' ?>"
                           style="left: <?php echo  $info['home_x']; ?>px; top: <?php echo $info['home_y']; ?>px;"
                           data-target=".country-popup-<?php echo $term->term_id ?>">
                            <div class="inner"></div>
                            <div class="text">
                                <span class="name"><?php echo $re[0] ?> </span>
                                    <span class="number"><?php echo " / ".$title; ?>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </a>

                        <?php
                    }
                }
            endforeach; ?>

        </div>
    </div>
```

and my custom field for CPT is;

```
  <tr>
        <th>
            <label><?php _e('Home X'); ?></label>
        </th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="_post_info[home_x]" value="<?php echo $info['home_x'] ?>">
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>
            <label><?php _e('Home Y'); ?></label>
        </th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="_post_info[home_y]" value="<?php echo $info['home_y'] ?>">
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Above code works perfectly for this purpose.

But I want to change the custom taxonomy as office and post as a country name now. Instead of creating multiple posts for the city, creating a country post and adding cities as custom taxonomy is much easier. So I am trying to change below code for a new way.

I have changed the loop code as below, and create a custom field for custom-taxonomy, I also indicate it below too.

New loop;

```
<div class="map-wrapper">
                <div class="map">

                    <?php

                    $terms = get_terms(array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'office-city',
                        'hide_empty' => false,
                    ));
                    ?>
                    <?php foreach ($terms as $term) : ?>
                        <?php
                        $re = explode('-', $term->name);
                        $args = array (
                            'post_type' => 'office-country', //
                            'posts_per_page' => -1,
                            'order' => 'ASC',
                            'tax_query'     => array(
                                array(
                                    'taxonomy'  => 'office-city',
                                    'field'     => 'id',
                                    'terms'     => $term->term_id,
                                ),
                            ),
                        );

                        $query = new WP_Query( $args );
                        if( $query->have_posts() ){
                            while( $query->have_posts() ){
                                $query->the_post();
                                $title =  get_the_title();
                                // $info = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_post_info', true);
                                $link = get_term_meta($term->term_id, 'link', true);
                                $MapY = get_term_meta($term->term_id, 'home_y', true);
                                $MapX = get_term_meta($term->term_id, 'home_x', true);
                                ?>
                                <a href="<?php echo $link ?>"
                                   class="point <?php if ($term->slug === $_GET['country']) echo 'active' ?>"
                                   style="left: <?php echo  $MapY ?>px; top: <?php echo $MapX ?>px;"
                                   data-target=".country-popup-<?php echo $term->term_id ?>">
                                    <div class="inner"></div>
                                    <div class="text">
                                        <span class="name"><?php echo $title; ?> </span>
                                            <span class="number"><?php echo " / ".$re[0] ?>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>

                                <?php
                            }
                        }
                    endforeach; ?>

                </div>
            </div>
```

Custom field for taxonomy;

```
add_action( 'office-country_edit_form_fields', 'office_country_taxonomy_custom_fields', 10, 2 );
function office_country_taxonomy_custom_fields($tag) {
    ?>

    <tr>
        <th>
            <label><?php _e('Home X'); ?></label>
        </th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="_term_meta[home_x]" value="<?php echo get_term_meta($tag->term_id, 'home_x', true)  ?>">
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>
            <label><?php _e('Home Y'); ?></label>
        </th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="_term_meta[home_y]" value="<?php echo get_term_meta($tag->term_id, 'home_y', true) ?>">
        </td>
    </tr>


    <?php
}
```

But when I applied this code, it partly works and I have no idea to change the query.

The result;

- USA/New York
- United Kingdom/London
- Spain/Barcelona

So, it does only show posts per taxonomy but I want to show all the cities per country like below;

- USA/New York
- USA/Chicago
- United Kingdom/London
- United Kingdom/Bristol
- Spain/Barcelona
- Spain/Granada

Sorry, it is a long question. I hope you guys can help on this, and I hope you guys understood my broken English.

Comment: I think the above change in code doesn't work since it works partially. It loops through the number of taxonomy. Why not change post type with country and add custom taxonomy as cities. Yes, you will loose all data but it works better.

Comment: @MohammadAshiqueAli thanks for your reply. Well taxonomy name is not really important now, i can anytime change it but the problem is actually Query. The loop is populating based on CTF not custom taxonomy. So there is currently 4 countries and 10 cities but it only lists 4 countries 4 cities. I want it to be listed all 10 cities with its country.

Comment: Can i confirm that Countries are custom taxonomy and Cities are CPT right?

Comment: Now the CPT is countries, and cities are category. Sorry I've forgotten to edit the taxonomy in the code.

Comment: I loop i guess is correct then since you have loop the category based at the beginning. I have doubt there is some issue inside the loop. :D

Comment: Yes, but somehow it does not generates multiple taxonomy based on one CPT post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188651/discussion-between-mohammad-ashique-ali-and-t-cvmk).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop is working correctly as i got result what you wanted.

```
<?php

$terms = get_terms(array(
    'taxonomy' => 'office-city',
    'hide_empty' => false,
));

foreach ($terms as $term) : 
    $args = array (
        'post_type' => 'office-country', //
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'tax_query'     => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy'  => 'office-city',
                'field'     => 'id',
                'terms'     => $term->term_id,
            ),
        ),
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if( $query->have_posts() ){
        while( $query->have_posts() ){
            $query->the_post();
            $title =  get_the_title();
            echo '<p>'. $title . '/' . $term->name . '</p>';
        }
    }
endforeach; ?>
```